# How to form an JSON formatted Mutable Array in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsmutablearray

I need to form a JSON Formatted Mutable Array based on the response, initially I get ID from DB from that DB I need to Check in an Empty array then Add Elements to the array with respect to Key values, when its runs for next time The Array contains ID so I have to append the KEY and Values to the Respective Id

Here my Sample Code:

```
if ([hashTableArr1 containsObject:assignItmId]) {
           //     [testDict setObject:assignItmId forKey:@"id"];

                [testDict2 setObject:keyname forKey:@"keyname"];
                [testDict2 setObject:value forKey:@"value"];
                [hashTableArr addObject:testDict2];
                [testDict setObject:hashTableArr forKey:@"result"];
                [hashTableArr1 addObject:testDict];

            }
            else{

                NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [dict2 setObject:assignItmId forKey:@"id"];
                [dict1 setObject:keyname forKey:@"keyname"];
                [dict1 setObject:value forKey:@"value"];
                [arr1 addObject:dict1];
                [dict2 setObject:arr1 forKey:@"result"];
                [hashTableArr1 addObject:dict2];
            }
```

My output is:

```
 (
    {
    id = "1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = "Date";
            value = "06-02-2017";
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = "1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = Vendor;
            value = "";
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = "1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = Owner;
            value = XXX;
        }
    );
},
```

**Expected Results :**

```
 (
    {
    id = "1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = "Purchase Date";
            value = "06-02-2017";
        },
    {
            keyname = Vendor;
            value = "";
        }, 
         {
            keyname = Owner;
            value = XXX;
        }

    );
}
```

Please Update the suitable solution

Comment: are you used loop for data population ? add whole code if your are used .

Comment: yes the process will run in loop mode

Comment: @batMan007 - if you are add array of dictionary then use `addObjectFromArray` not `addObject`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is you are adding an array in result key every time and then dictionary into your main array but for your expected result you have to maintain an array outside the loop and add the object into your array which you maintain outside the loop and after this add this array in result key of a dictionary and then add this dictionary into main array.

You have to put this code outside from your loop

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict2 setObject:assignItmId forKey:@"id"];

NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

In Loop

```
if ([hashTableArr1 containsObject:assignItmId]) {
       //     [testDict setObject:assignItmId forKey:@"id"];

            [testDict2 setObject:keyname forKey:@"keyname"];
            [testDict2 setObject:value forKey:@"value"];
            [arr1 addObject:testDict2];

        }
        else{

            NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict1 setObject:keyname forKey:@"keyname"];
            [dict1 setObject:value forKey:@"value"];
            [arr1 addObject:dict1];

        }
```

After loop

```
            [dict2 setObject:arr1 forKey:@"result"];
            [hashTableArr1 addObject:dict2];
```

Comment: actually the process running in While loop in DB Call

Comment: Actually i don't know what is the remaining code which you not post, but what are you getting right now is because of this issue which I explained.